# Filtering Pandas Dataframe Based on List of Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, wildcard

I have a pandas dataframe which has may be 1000 Columns. However I do not need so many columns> I need columns only if they match/starts/contains specific strings.

So lets say I have a dataframe columns like
df.columns =

```
  HYTY, ABNH, CDKL, GHY@UIKI,  BYUJI@#hy  BYUJI@tt  BBNNII#5  FGATAY@J ....
```

I want to select columns whose name are only like HYTY, CDKL, BYUJI* & BBNNI*

So what I was trying to do is to create a list of regular expressions like:

```
  import re 

  relst = ['HYTY', 'CDKL*', 'BYUJI*', 'BBNI*']


  my_w_lst = [re.escape(s) for s in relst]

  mask_pattrn = '|'.join(my_w_lst)
```

Then I create the logical vector to give me a list of TRUE/FALSE to say whether the string is present or not. However,  not understanding how to get the dataframe of only those true selected columns from this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using what you already have you can pass your mask to filter like:

```
df.filter(regex=mask_pattrn)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this works. But I have another complication. Say I have columns like 'HYTY,', 'HYTY$$$^3' & 'HYTY#LO' etc But I need only 'HYTY' and not other two. How can I do that using the previous script? Thanks.again!

Comment: Since it is a regex you can use '$' after HYTY to signify the end of the expression. Like 'HYTY$'

Comment: Got it! Thanks. What about if a pattern ends in say YUYAT, Will I do ^.?

Comment: 'YUYAT' allows nothing or anything before and nothing or anything after. If you only want columns that end in YUYAT you can tack on the '$' to the end. Any column with additional characters after 'T' will be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

We can do `startswith`

```
relst = ['CDKL', 'BYUJI', 'BBNI']

subdf = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith(tuple(relst))|df.columns.isin(['HYTY'])]
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this partilly works. But I have another complication. Say I have columns like 'HYTY,', 'HYTY$$$^3' & 'HYTY#LO' etc But I need only 'HYTY' and not other two. How can I do that using the previous script? Thanks.again!

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall()`. It will give you a list of columns to pass to `df[mylist]`